# sitefinity version 11 open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph, sitefinity

We recently upgraded to version 11 and would like to take advantage of the Open Graph functionality for our blog posts.  I have followed the instructions here:  https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/open-graph-settings

I have turned on the usage of Open Graph in the *Settings >> Advanced >> System >> SEO and Open Graph properties >> Enable Open Graph Properties* configuration of the site and restarted Sitefinity (not sure I had to do that last step but I figured it wouldn't hurt).

I have also set up the custom fields as described in the "Configure Open Graph properties" step of the instructions in the link below.

However, my understanding is that using these instructions we are supposed to get the `<meta property="og:title" content="<!-- the Open Graph title that you specified -->">`  and so forth in the page's HTML.  I am not seeing those properties being set in the `<head>` nor anywhere else.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In order for these tags to render you must be in single content view, ie the details of a content item. Sitefinity 11.1 is coming with page level support for OG meta.

> if you paste a link of the detailed view of a News item on Facebook, you can configure an Open Graph title, description, and image for this News item.

from: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/open-graph-settings